# Autodesk Forge reading from text file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, autodesk-data-management

I was just wondering if there is a way to push a text file to Autodesk forge. I've completed a few examples of pushing 3D models to the forge viewer but was wondering if there was a way to push an average text file and for it to be displayed through Forge?

Just an idea of mine, would love to hear of the possibilities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Data Management APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2) will let you upload any content you want, but the [Model Derivative APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2) are meant to be used with **CAD** file formats (and a few additional formats like PDF). You can see all the available translations here: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations. General text files are not supported.